# Website open in quirksmode by default

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, doctype, quirks-mode

I have some problems designing a WP-based website ([www.interactiva.cc/~cristall/cristallini](http://www.interactiva.cc/~cristall/cristallini))
It works fine on all the browser, but not in IE 9 (is it something new ? ;)). 
I tried to declare the DOCTYPE to avoid the quirksmode with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

However it still erase completely any CSS rule I have used.

What can I do ?

Thank you !

Comment: To begin with, you are declaring two doctypes. I don't think that's good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, change this:

```
<!--Theme by StefanoCavaliere.it-->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
```

To this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<!--Theme by StefanoCavaliere.it-->
```

And note since your webpage is configured to use Chrome in IE (ver 8 at least), use Inspect Element on the Browsers Context Menu and do not use IE's Developer Tools via F12 key.

Also, your link tags should be self closing. After the `DOCTYPE` fix, see your errors [**here**](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.interactiva.cc%2F~cristall%2Fcristallini%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3) with tips on where to fix them at.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this tag to the head:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```